# Get Start day and End day of a Week? [Java]

Tags: java, android-calendar, android-date, date, java-calendar

I am developing an app that constantly monitors the user's physical activity and inactivity levels. I am trying to figure out out to get the starting and ending day of a week when a date is provided. For example, 3 Mar is the date that I am providing and I want to get the starting and ending day of this week -> 27 Feb - 5 Mar. Is it possible to do that?

I am trying to achieve the following design
[image]

The following code that I currently have just concatenates the last and first date of the list of activities (one for every day is created).

```
private String formatDate(List<Activity> activities) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.UK);
    Date date = activities.get(activities.size() - 1).getDate();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    String output = "" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " "
            + calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.UK);

    calendar.setTime(activities.get(0).getDate());

    output += " - " + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " "
            + calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.UK);
    return output;
}
```

*Note: I have to mention that the List as a parameter are all of the activities grouped per week already*

However, with this approach it becomes problematic when the person is not using the app (i.e. not logged in -> the app stops monitoring) and the text label could look something like that
[image] 
(e.g. only one activity for this week)

Any advice please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as simple as doing:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
```

What is considered the first day of the week depends on the `Locale` used.

To get the last day of the week then do:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 6);
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked brilliantly! I added my working method as a solution to my question as well :)

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:**

For [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) week (Monday to Sunday), you can use `ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK` as 1 for the first day of the week and as 7 for the last day of the week.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.MARCH, 3);

        LocalDate firstDayOfTheWeek = date.with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
        System.out.println(firstDayOfTheWeek); // 2017-02-27

        LocalDate lastDayOfTheWeek = date.with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);
        System.out.println(lastDayOfTheWeek); // 2017-03-05
    }
}
```

Alternatively,

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.MARCH, 3);

        LocalDate firstDayOfTheWeek = date.with(WeekFields.ISO.getFirstDayOfWeek());
        System.out.println(firstDayOfTheWeek); // 2017-02-27

        LocalDate lastDayOfTheWeek = firstDayOfTheWeek.plusDays(6);
        System.out.println(lastDayOfTheWeek); // 2017-03-05
    }
}
```

Use [`WeekFields#of(Locale locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#of-java.util.Locale-) to get the `Locale`-specific result (thanks, Ole V.V. for the suggestion):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.MARCH, 3);

        System.out.println("France:");
        LocalDate firstDayOfTheWeek = date.with(WeekFields.of(Locale.FRANCE).getFirstDayOfWeek());
        System.out.println(firstDayOfTheWeek);

        LocalDate lastDayOfTheWeek = firstDayOfTheWeek.plusDays(6);
        System.out.println(lastDayOfTheWeek);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("USA:");
        firstDayOfTheWeek = date.with(WeekFields.of(Locale.US).getFirstDayOfWeek());
        System.out.println(firstDayOfTheWeek);

        lastDayOfTheWeek = firstDayOfTheWeek.plusDays(6);
        System.out.println(lastDayOfTheWeek);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
France:
2017-02-27
2017-03-05

USA:
2017-03-05
2017-03-11
```

The documentation of `WeekFields.ISO.getFirstDayOfWeek()` says:

> Gets the first day-of-week.
>
> The first day-of-week varies by culture. For example, the US uses
> Sunday, while France and the ISO-8601 standard use Monday. This method
> returns the first day using the standard DayOfWeek enum.

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: I believe that your code will give ISO weeks (Monday to Sunday). One may want to use a `WeekFields` object of the desired locale to get the weeks right for other week schemes.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` parameter to work out how many days to subtract - for example to print the start and end of the current week:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

    // Subtract number of days to start of week
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1));

    String output = "" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " "
            + calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.UK);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
    output += " - " + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " "
            + calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.UK);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. You and @john16384 's pointed me to the right direction. Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BarrySW19 and @john16384, here is the working method:

```
private String formatDate(List<Activity> activities) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.UK);
    Date date = activities.get(activities.size() - 1).getDate();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());

    String output = "" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " "
            + calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.UK);

    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 6);

    output += " - " + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " "
            + calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.UK);
    return output;
}
```